# Verifying the Regression Assumptions

Tags: regression, residuals, assumptions

I have residual plots like the following:

[image]

Should I be concerned about the large hump for the higher quantiles on the normal Q-Q plot? Would some sort of a transformation on the response variable help? I am unsure where to go to now. My model is significant.

Comment: The scale location plot shows variance increasing with mean and the plot of residuals and leverage show a number of points with high leverage. I would sort out why you are seeing the outlying points first before investigating transformation. Without more details about your model it is impossible to give a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Q-Q plot is showing positive skew. R package `trafo` is designed to show how transforms affect model assumptions.

Comparing the untransformed model with a transformed model (the default is the Box-Cox transformation) is done as follows:

```
R> linMod_trafo <- trafo_lm(linMod)
R> diagnostics(linMod_trafo)
R> plot(linMod_trafo)
```

See the [R Journal Vol. 11/2, December 2019](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2019-2/) for a nice explanation.